# setup trigger for file change in teamcity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I can setup teamcity trigger to run tests whenever there in VCS checkin/ change.

Then I setup `command line` build steps to access files on system .

e.g. `custom script'

```
cd ~/Desktop
ls
```

But is there way to trigger test run if there is change in file e.g. `test.txt`

I want to setup trigger as 'if file changes run tests'.

Or it has to be git checkin?

Comment: So `test.txt` is not in your VCS? Where is it? How does the build config access it?

Comment: @sferencik it's on system e.g. Desktop

Answer (score 4):

You would add a new "VCS Trigger" under your project configuration and you would add a new "Trigger rules" specifying the file/directory that should trigger the build. For example: +:root=ContecIT:ContecRepairSystem/** (here I am saying monitor the VCS root "ContecIT", and watch for any files changes under the "ContecRepairSystem" directory.

Comment: the file isn't in vcs directory. It's on system e.g. Desktop

Comment: Exactly what I needed for our situation.

Comment: If your build depends on a file, I'd recommend putting it in your VCS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any "FileSystemWatcher" feature in TC for triggering builds, unfortunately. Sounds like a good idea for a new TC plugin.

I've checked ([here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/TeamCity+Plugins)) if perhaps there's such a plugin already. Seems not. The "Url Build Trigger" comes closest. You could try to fork and adjust it to suit your needs.

I think your use case is quite rare. Usually a TC farm comprises many TC agents, each running on a different machine. Thus, they can't monitor the same filesystem (e.g. the `Desktop` directory), except perhaps some shared folders...

Answer (score 0):

VCS trigger configuration would monitor for any git checkin and triggers the build process

[image: VCSTrigger settings]